# How to get the list item as url parameter in django

Tags: python, django, url, django-templates

I'm trying to use a list item as a parameter in a URL tag in Django, but unable to use it.

Everytime it gives `django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'film_details' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['refs/film_details/(?P<pk>[^/]+)/$']`
Upon lots of searching, I found out that there is a problem with accessing the list item.
My question is how do I use the list item as a parameter in the URL tag?

**View function**

```
def search_field(request):
    search_text = request.POST.get('search')

    refs = Ref.objects.filter(title__icontains=search_text).values('id','title')
    year = ImdbFilm.objects.filter(year__icontains=search_text).values('title')
    filmNames = ImdbFilm.objects.filter(title__icontains=search_text).values('year','crew__name')
    
    results = list(chain(refs,year,filmNames))[:10]
    
    context = {'results': results}
    return render(request,'refs/search-results.html', context)
```

**Url Tag**

```
{% for film in results %}
    <li>
        <a href="{% url 'refs:film_details' film.id %}"> 
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

**urls.py  file**

```
path("film_details/<str:pk>/", views.film_details, name="film_details")
```

Comment: try 

{% for film in context.results %}

Comment: you have to pass "pk" as an argument in the function: def search_field(request, pk)

Comment: @Diego Don't worry about pk, it is another function which is generating the list.

Comment: @AdamJames but the problem is with url tag. I can easily access values as variables but unable to access it in the url tag.

Comment: <a href="{% url 'refs:film_details' pk=film.id %}"

Comment: Your `results` list is a combination of different types of objects, where not all of them have an `id`...

Answer (score -1):

The code in urls.py and in your html are fine. In your views.py you want results of your Ref model. If you have a ForeignKey field to ImdbFilm then you can access everything of ImdbFilm by dot-notation (also in html template).

If you want 10 results, you could also use pagination (https://pypi.org/project/django-pagination/) Maybe this function could help:

```
def search_field(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        searched = request.POST['searched']
        print(searched)
        results = Ref.objects.filter(title__icontains=search_text).order_by("whatever")
        # test fk:
        for ref in results:
            print(f'year={ref.imdb_film.year} name={ref.imdb_film.crew__name}'
            # this dot notation you can also do in your html's for loop if you do have a foreignkey to ImdbFilm.
    paginator = Paginator(list_all, 10)
    page_number = request.GET.get('page')
    ten_results = paginator.get_page(page_number)
    context = {"ten_results": ten_results}
    return render(request, 'refs/search-results.html', context)
```

html:

```
{% for film in ten_results %}
    <li>
        <a href="{% url 'refs:film_details' film.id %}"> 
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. I want to access the value of id key in the url tag. I can get it in variable tag why not in url tag. It has nothing to do with the pagination.